# How would I reference something in From a FXML file, in Main?

Tags: java, javafx, fxml

Hello everyone I'm trying to learn JavaFX.

IS there anyway I can change one of these nodes or elements from the main.java file.
How would I go about changing lowTextField text from the main.java file?

I try using
              lowTextField.setText("Still learning"); in the start method and that sets off kinds of errors. Null Pointers etc. Which makes since because I just do not know how to reference that textfield from the fxml in main java.
 How would I go about doing that?

This is the Main:

```
public class Main extends Application {

  @Override
     public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception{
          Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("sample.fxml"));
    primaryStage.setTitle("Hello World");
    primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root, 300, 275));
    primaryStage.show();

        lowTextField.setText("This is The Console"); //<<this des not work


   }


public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
   }
 }
```

This is my Controller File. It does nothing right now but I understand that the controller is for actions, inputs etc.

```
          public class Controller{

@FXML Button toolBarBtn1;
@FXML Button toolBarBtn2;
@FXML TextField lowTextField;
@FXML public BorderPane Root;

   }
```

I know it's really something simple that I'm doing, but I'm just trying to get an idea.

I would really appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ideally, you would not want to directly change a field in a different class.  Instead, in your Controller class, create setters and getters to manipulate the fields.

Here is a sample of what you can place in Controller.java:

```
public void setLowTextField (String text) {
  this.lowTextField.setText(text);  // Calls the setText() method of the local TextField
}
```

Then in your Main.java file, just call that method after the Controller has been created.

```
FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("sample.fxml"));

// You first need to create a reference to your controller
Controller controller = new Controller();
loader.setController(controller);

Parent root = loader.load()

// Now call the setter from the Controller.java file:
controller.setLowTextField("This is The Console");

primaryStage.setTitle("Hello World");
primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root, 300, 275));
primaryStage.show();
```

This is considered a best practice as you can declare your @FXML variables in Controller.java as private, but still access them from the Main class.

Comment: You need to set the controller on the `FXMLLoader` instance, not on the `Parent`. (`Parent` has no `setController(...)` method.)

Comment: Ah, oops!  I have corrected my answer.  Thanks, @James_D

Comment: And you also need to call `setController()` before you call `load()`, otherwise the fields won't get injected...

Comment: I really appreciate the help but I'm getting this error :  Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception in Application start method
 at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication1(LauncherImpl.java:917)
 at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication$155(LauncherImpl.java:182)
 at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: javafx.fxml.LoadException: Controller value already specified.

Comment: @jmorgan - You're getting that error because your FXML file likely also contains a value for the controller.  Remove the `fx:controller` tag from the FXML file and you should be able to run it without an issue.  In your case, you want to be able to manipulate the controller during the load of the FXML, so you need to declare it in code instead of the FXML file.

Comment: Thanks again! Can't believe I missed that, seemed like common sense.

Comment: You actually don't really need to do that, since you're not doing anything other than calling the default constructor for the controller. You could just call `loader.getController()` after loading the FXML, omit the call to create the controller etc and set the controller class in the usual way.

Answer (score 1):

If you define an `initialize()` method in the controller, it will be invoked after the `@FXML`-annotated fields are injected, so you can access them there:

```
public class Controller{

    @FXML Button toolBarBtn1;
    @FXML Button toolBarBtn2;
    @FXML TextField lowTextField;
    @FXML BorderPane Root;

    public void initialize() {
        lowTextField.setText("This is The Console"); 
    }

}
```